# Расстановка запятых (не падая, наконец, как никогда)

Tags: пунктуация

1. Я пока еще могу стоять на ногах() не падая.
2. Тогда он() наконец() положил трубку.
   Когда она() наконец() закончила говорить.
3. После четырех занятий подряд() я был вымотан() как никогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я пока еще могу стоять на ногах не пАдая. Нет паузы, деепричастие в роли наречия. Но обособление тоже возможно (здесь, скорее, авторское решение).

Тогда он наконец положил трубку. Когда она наконец закончила говорить. Здесь "наконец" в роли обстоятельства (в классическом варианте в качестве вводного слова оно обозначает (1) перечисление или (2) чувство нетерпения). Но иногда возможно авторское решение (то есть обособление обстоятельства, отнесение его на второй план).

"После четырех занятий подряд  я был вымотан как никогдА". "Как никогда" - обстоятельство, тесно связанное с глаголом, нет паузы, ударение падает на обстоятельство.