# Корректна ли постановка знаков?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Корректна ли постановка знаков?

> Наконец, после долгих поисков, семья вышла из дома.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415757/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0 и https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f